# update ng-option value from another select option

Tags: angularjs

I have to update another select statement based from another select

i have look at samples from the web and other postings here in stack but they lack something.

What I am looking for is that:

```
<select ng-model="topSelect" ng-change="updateBottomSelect()>
    <option value="ONE">ONE</option>
    <option value="TWO">TWO</option>
    <option value="THREE">THREE</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="botSelect">
    <option value="ONE">ONE</option>
    <option value="TWO">TWO</option>
    <option value="THREE">THREE</option>
</select>
```

I have tried:

```
$scope.updateBottomSelect = function(){
if(topSelect == 'ONE'){
  botSelect = "ONE";
 }else if(topSelect == 'TWO'){
  botSelect = "TWO";
 }else if(topSelect == 'THREE'){
  botSelect = "THREE";
 }
}
```

What i want is to really display in the options the values not blank. Some samples that i saw in some forums were they leave the bottom select blank ang have to allow users to select from them

Answer (score 1):

You may have try this way:-

```
$scope.updateBottomSelect = function() {
  $scope.botSelect = angular.copy($scope.topSelect); 
}
```